# How to put a "V" flag in a PowerBI dynamic filter?

Tags: filter, menu, powerbi, bookmarks

["V" flag as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Eg1.png)

I have to put a "V" flag like the one showed in the picturein one bookmark in PowerBi, now when you select the filter there is not a "v" flag but only black. Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is a bit unclear what you are asking. What is the "V"-flag, and what is only black? You need to provide some code example, and be more specific.

Comment: there isn't code.. it's a front-end change, but I try to be more clear: in a drop down menù, you can choose something and filter, when you have choosen, usually there is a square with the "V" mark that shew you what you have choosen. it is a tipical "sign" for example when you end a task in your agenda, you mark it with "V" thai is called "V" flag. Now... I have to put this "V" flag in my drop down menù in PowerBI. I hope that this explenation is clearer than in the previous request.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack**overflow**
I think what you are wanting to show are the check-marks (or chevron mark) next to the selected item in a filter list.
Normally by default, the option for Multi-select is ON, if you turn it OFF then it will allow you to select one item from the list, putting the "V" next to it.

If you want the "V" to be color or any other symbol, you will have to make you own list and add special characters as I did in my KPI column. See picture
The circle Character I used in a calculated Measure was :  UNICHAR(11044) which can change color...

So to select your chevron mark "V" display follow these steps:

- Select your Filter
- Open the Format pane (the one with the paint roller)
- Open your V-Selection controls
- Change Multi-select with CRTL position to OFF
- Test your filter again

Please see images below:

[Changing Multi-Select to display check mark symbol on dropdown filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX8za.png)

Multi-select causes the box to show all Black, as you indicated.
[Black box on selected items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQc8z.png) -

Color symbols on Grid Lists - picture: 
[Symbols with color added to grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXiFP.png)

Hope this helps,
in bocca al lupo, 
Andres

Other symbols you can use :
https://www.alt-codes.net/root-symbols